# Getting a ReturnValue from cmd.Parameters in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, parameters

I have just finished converted a vb.net app to c# and one of the lines is to get @ReturnValue from the parameter.

I ended up having to CAST a lot of things..

Is there not a easier way

here is what i have

```
int rc = ((System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlInt32)(((System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter)(cmd.Parameters["@ReturnValue"])).SqlValue)).Value;
```

In vb.net it was as simple as doing this

```
Dim rc As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters("@ReturnValue").Value)
```

Alot easier :-)

But the problem with C# is the property Value isn't available unless I Cast to SqlParameter and i also need to cast to Sqltypes.SqlInt32  - i can't just do a standard Convert.ToInt32

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't a C# versus VB.NET thing - it's about the types you're using to declare your variables. If `cmd` is an `IDbCommand`, you're in for a lot of casting.

The [`IDbCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idbcommand.parameters.aspx) property returns an [`IDataParametersCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idataparametercollection.aspx), which contains a collection of Object instances. Since Object doesn't have a property called `Value`, you need to cast each instance to [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) before accessing Value.

[`SqlCommand.Parameters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx), by contrast is a [`SqlParameterCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.aspx), which contains a collection of [`SqlParameter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx) instances. If you declare your `cmd` variable as a `SqlCommand`, you can access its parameters' values in the straightforward way to which you're accustomed. (At the cost of being tightly coupled to the implementations in the SqlClient namespace.)

Answer (score 2):

It's just as easy to do it in C#:

```
int rc = (int) cmd.Parameters("@ReturnValue").Value;
```

Comment: The OP wrote: "the problem with C# is the property Value isn't available unless I cast ..."